# Rotating Object doesn't work quite right

Tags: transforms

Every time I try to rotate something in a certain direction, it only rotates it on the X-axis.

[image]

Comment: Maybe others axis are locked (check the N properties panel, lock icons). Maybe constraints. Maybe share your file.

Comment: Please use the built-in tools [to upload images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) only to imgur. Also, all-caps and fat text doesn't add information. If you want to share your file for us to check, please do so by using  [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), then edit your question and insert the given link.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually rotating on the Z axis, but that's beside the point.
Try saving the scene, closing down Blender, then open Blender and the scene again and see if it's still like that. 
If you had a Limit Rotation constraint on the object, with the Limit X and Limit Y axes ticked, and the Min and Max values left on the defaults of zero, you would get that effect, but I think you'd have noticed that you put a constraint there. But check you haven't done that - if you're clicking around to explore, you can forget what you've done.
If the axes were simply locked, you shouldn't see a ring on the rotate widget for the locked axes, but they are visible in your animation, but if Blender has a glitch and hasn't updated the display, maybe the axes are locked.